# ImageView inside LinearLayout is having margins on sides by default

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-imageview

I am wondering and still can't find the issue.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"/>

    <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/someImage"
            android:id="@+id/kioskModeImageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

For above structure my ImageView is being shortened on sides and have some weird margins on left and right which i don't know what they come from.

When I remove the FrameLayout from the LinearLayout (and have ImageView only as a one thing) in a container everything works as expected - image takes the whole place as match_parent should work

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/customer_dark_1"
            android:id="@+id/kioskModeImageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

What is causing that issue?

Answer (score 0):

You have not set scaleType to your imageview, Try setting `android:scaleType="fitXY"` there are other values for scaleType, try using one that suits your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

In your case `match_parent` `match_parent` don't work on image with `FrameLayout`.
You need to add `layout_weight` and set `layout_height="0dp"` to make it look like expected

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"/>

    <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/someImage"
            android:id="@+id/kioskModeImageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Also, in this article explained about `ImageView scaleType`:

https://thoughtbot.com/blog/android-imageview-scaletype-a-visual-guide